# After remove the www extension from addressbar session not working

Tags: php, www-authenticate

After login in this url `www.example.com`, if I remove the `www` extension from address-bar  the login detail value doesnot keep by session.

Comment: You might want to read up on cookie domains.

Comment: in login code there is no-error. i want to know if i remove the www from addressbar like(example.com) after login, it's does not keep the seesion values why it's happen? plz clear to me!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a redirect function from non-www to www. See this topic: [WWW to non-WWW Redirect with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079457/www-to-non-www-redirect-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

put this in your globals, or in your includes file, or just add it before any `session_start()` call.

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain",".example.com");
```

another option would be to to add this:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
```

to your `.htaccess`

Comment: thanks man, but i want to set one cookie value for both example.com and www.example.com. if i add or remove the www from address it will be stay with same cookies, what i am do for that!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @tamildinesh yes, the code above will do exactly what you want.. just try it.
I've also added one more option for you

Answer (score 1):

Your session is maintained by a cookie. When you log on to www.example.com, a cookie is saved for this domain by default, which is represented with every request to a URL in this domain. example.com is a different cookie domain, and the cookie won't therefore be presented.

Solutions are to either redirect from example.com to www.example.com as Andrei suggested, or to make the cookie domain match as Adnan suggests - both valid answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing browser cache
deleting temporary files and prefetch files
clear dns from cmd ipconfig/flushdns

re open browser login, writing or removing www should not alter with session since it runs on server.

make sure you are not Re - Starting session.