# Redirect from www to non-www in php?

Tags: php, redirect

Google pagespeed service is having trouble today.
They are serving my www content.

So I need a quick fix I can put on top of my index php file, to redirect the users to the non-www version, with current page and all.

So if a user lands on my site on www.test.com/some-page/
they will be redirected to test.com/some-page/ instantly

Whats a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a .htaccess file with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079457/www-to-non-www-redirect-with-php) explains a solution using PHP instead.